# animate images in cocos2d

Tags: core-animation, cocos2d-iphone

I am newbie in cocos2D But have developed several view based application.
So what I want to know is:

Is there any alternate ,for  **animationImages** used for animating the images in imageview, in cocos2D?

I want to use the same thing i.e: Animate the images same as any gif file.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animation in Cocos2D is handled by the CCAnimation class, you can read the documentation here:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_animation.html

There are a number of examples for animating sprites, using a Sprite Sheet, single Images, a Texture Cache, etc.

This is one of my favorite ones:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1271/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d